# Почему после смены пользователя командой `su` нужно два раза вводить `exit` для закрытия bash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian

> `exit` - Exit the shell, returning a status of n to the shell’s parent.
>   [Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

su запускает какую нибудь программу с правами другого пользователя, он никак не может повлиять на права текущей программы из которой он запущен. По умолчанию su в качестве такой программы запускает bash (или другой дефолтный интерпретатор). В итоге у вас выходит, что запущен один bash с правами пользователя и из него другой bash с правами рута. Поэтому и выходить вам приходится 2 раза по очереди, сначала из одного, потом из другого. (P.S. если exit писать лень, можно пользоваться Ctrl+D :) )

Comment: Т.е. это не subshell?

Comment: @Hipster Не знаю как реализовывается subshell, самое простое было бы сделать fork(), или вообще поток. но в обоих случаях bash не может изменить эффекивного пользователя. su это отдельная программа. все что она делает, проверив права, меняет эффективного пользователя _собственного процесса_, через seteuid(), после чего выполняет exec() т.е. загружает в свое адресное пространство другую программу (bash). вызывающий bash ничего не подозревает о том, что программа внутри стала таким же bash, с его точки зрения это отдельный процесс, в котором выполняется su

Comment: Ясно. Теперь понял. Спасибо.